# What could cause Redis RDB Snapshoting to Stall?

Tags: redis

I have a redis install on Ubuntu 14.04, and I seem to have nearly weekly issues with RDB snapshots completing.  Redis version is 3.0.4 64 bit.

> 3838:M 24 Feb 09:46:28.826 * Background saving terminated with success 
>   3838:M 24 Feb 09:47:29.088 * 100000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving... 
>   3838:M 24 Feb 09:47:29.230 * Background saving started by pid 17281 
> 17281:signal-handler (1456338079) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown... 
>   3838:M 24 Feb 13:24:19.358 # Background saving terminated by signal 9 
>   3838:M 24 Feb 13:24:19.622 * 10 changes in 900 seconds. Saving... 
>   3838:M 24 Feb 13:24:19.730 * Background saving started by pid 17477

What you see there is that at 9:47am the background save started, but when I found it at 1:24pm it appeared to be completely stalled.  I found the forked process to have basically no activity - the amount of memory it was consuming wasn't increasing.  I tried to "kill" the child process, but it never actually quit, so i had to kill it with extreme prejudice (-9).

When things are getting bad, I get the following errors in my app:

> 2016-02-24 13:11:12,046 [2344] ERROR kCollectors.Main - Error while adding to Redis: No connection is available to service this operation: SADD ALLCH

My redis config is to do rdb snapshots only (no AOF).  The load is modification heavy, with thousands of writes per second.

Currently I'm at the point where no redis background save is succeeding, and the background process becomes so much larger than the regular process that my VM starts swapping.  Here's my TOP.  3838 is my redis instance, and 17477 is the background save process (as noted above):

> top - 14:06:42 up 118 days,  2:05,  1 user,  load average: 1.07, 1.07, 1.13
>  
>   Tasks:  81 total,   3 running,  78 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie 
>   %Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 45.8 id, 51.3 wa,  0.0 hi, 
>   0.5 si,  0.0 st 
>   KiB Mem:   8176996 total,  8036792 used,   140204 free,      120 buffers
>   KiB Swap:  6289404 total,  3968236 used,  2321168 free.     4044 cached Mem
>
> PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
>    36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   2.3  0.0
>   288:05.05 kswapd0
>   3838 rrr      20   0 7791836 3.734g    612 S   2.0
>   47.9 330:08.65 redis-server 
>   17477 rrr      20   0 7792228 6.606g    364 D   1.0 84.7   0:43.49 redis-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very interesting since I don't remember to ever read of such issues, so to discover the root cause could be very useful.

So here you are reporting a child process that stays a long time active, and even continues to allocate memory. I've no explanation for this if not a data corruption in the process memory, causing the RDB process to find unexpected conditions and looping forever in some way.

A few questions:

1. Does this happen even if you restart the process? (However please DON'T DO IT if you can avoid restarting and you did not restated yet, otherwise we may no longer understand the root cause).
2. While the RDB saving is active, do you see the CPU usage to be high and the process running with ps/top?
3. Could you try to interrupt the process with `gdb -p <pid>` and obtain a stack trace of the process?
4. Could you provide Redis `INFO` output to check version and other configuration things and state?
5. Could you check `free` output while this happens?

**TLDR**: is it possible the system is out of memory and is swapping a lot? So the child process while saving the RDB file visited all the pages and forced everything to be in the Resident Set. The system can't cope with so much I/O so it takes ages to complete the RDB saving.

**EDIT:** I just noticed you reported memory info:

KiB Mem: 8176996 total, 8036792 used, 140204 free, 120 buffers

So the system is out of memory and is swapping like crazy, and this results in the above behavior. As RDB saving starts, COW will use a lot of additional memory pushing the server on the memory limits.

Thanks.

Comment: The memory stats are from after the rdb child has been going for a while.  It didn't start in a swapping state - in fact, it was far from it.  It got into that state after a period of about 10-15 minutes of writing the rdb.  Regarding if it happens after restarting the process, do you mean restarting the child or restarting the parent?  I've restarted the child before and it ends up in the same state.  I end up having to bring down my entire redis and have it start up again.  Cpu is never high - never really above 10%.  Tomorrow I will try to get redis info (though I gave version)

Comment: Btw... I see that you are the redis God :-)  thanks so much for answering.  When it happens again I will be sure to capture as much as I can.  If I do capture swapping, is the answer only to add memory?  I feel like that's a dumb question, but I feel the need to ask...  My IT guy hates that this thing is so memory big already.  I know I could start a cluster, but I'd have to stand up at least 2 more nodes to get any reduction in per node size, so total memory footprint in our farm grows significantly...

Comment: @longofest 8G is really not a lot of RAM for a server these days. my laptop is running twice that.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Oh, I agree.  Hard to convince IT departments of that though.

Comment: Caught it again, and indeed, my server was swapping.  Thanks for the feedback.